# Accessing items in UIDynamicItemBehavior with Optional return value

Tags: objective-c, swift

I want to rewrite this Objective-C method in Swift.
I'm trying to find the best way to do it.

```
- (UIDynamicItemBehavior*) itemBehaviourForView:(UIView*)view
{
    for (UIDynamicItemBehavior* behaviour in _animator.behaviors)
    {
        if (behaviour.class == [UIDynamicItemBehavior class] && [behaviour.items firstObject] == view)
        {
            return behaviour;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

I wrote something like that:

```
func itemBehaviorForView(view :UIView)->UIDynamicItemBehavior
{
    for dynamicItemBehavior in animator.behaviors
    {
        if dynamicItemBehavior is UIDynamicItemBehavior  && dynamicItemBehavior.items.firstObject == view
        {
            return dynamicItemBehavior as UIDynamicItemBehavior
        }

    }
    return nil
}
```

I see two problems:

1. `dynamicItemBehavior.items.firstObject` is not `Array`, so there is no `firstObject` method
2. I cannot return `nil`

What should I do about these?

Comment: This question's title is too broad; suggest changing to 'Accessing Items in UIDynamicItemBehavior w/ Optional Return'

Answer (score 1):

If there is a possibility that the function will return `nil` then the function's return type needs to be an *optional*.  In your case declare the function as:

```
func itemBehaviorForView (view:UIView) -> UIDynamicItemBehavior?
```

The documentation for `UIDynamicItemBehavior` declares `items` as an array with:

```
var items: [AnyObject]! { get }
```

and thus you would reference the first object using array subscript notation as:

```
dynamicItemBehavior.items[0]
```

Of course, the `items` might be empty.  To handle that in idiomatic Swift use:

```
    if dynamicItemBehavior is UIDynamicItemBehavior {
      if let firstView = dynamicItemBehavior.items?[0] {
        if firstView == view {
          return dynamicItemBehavior as UIDynamicItemBehavior
        }
      }
    }
```

where the use of `if let <var>` will bind `<var>` iff the result of `...items?` is not `nil`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I cant to declare the type of items on dIB. items it's belongs to UIDynamicItemBehavior class. so now yore code is not compile, Actually now the problem is how can I iterate a collection of items that are not defined

Comment: In the documentation for `UIDynamicItemBehavior` is shows `items` as an `[AnyObject]!`.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: @GoZoner, code does not compile. Throws an error: Type 'AnyObject' cannot be implicitly downcast to 'NSObject'...

Comment: What line?  Try `view as AnyObject`?

Comment: `if firstView == view {` - xCode suggest to add `as NSObject`

Comment: However you should be doing `===` to check for reference as Objective-C code does.

Comment: With `===` no error occurs. Since we just compare references/pointers to class instances which is OK with whatever type.

Answer (score 0):

More functional approach after conversion:

```
let r = (animator.behaviors.filter { $0 is UIDynamicItemBehavior } as [UIDynamicItemBehavior])
    .filter({ $0.items?[0] === view })

return r.count > 0 ? r[0] : nil
```

And we can even shrink it to one line return if we `bridgeToObjectiveC()` the result to take advantage of `firstObject` property:

```
return (animator.behaviors.filter { $0 is UIDynamicItemBehavior } as [UIDynamicItemBehavior])
    .filter({ $0.items?[0] === view }).bridgeToObjectiveC().firstObject as? UIDynamicItemBehavior
```

**Remarks:**

Objective-C `==` to compare references in Swift achieved with `===`.

*I know that initial Objective-C algorithm was eager and returned as soon as match found. Show the expressiveness of functional approach.*

Answer (score 0):

I think Keenle was on the right track with using a functional style. But this is not a job for `filter`, this is a job for `find`. It will stop early on the first match it encounters. Unfortunately Swift does not currently implement `find` for us (unlike `filter`), but we can add it with extensions!

Unlike the other answers here, I don't know the type of animator or behaviors. I'm going to assume that behaviors is an NSArray, if that assumption is incorrect, please let me know.

```
extension NSArray {
    func find(predicate: (AnyObject) -> Bool) -> AnyObject? {
        for element: AnyObject in self {
            if predicate(element) {
                return element
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Now we just have to update your function to use this!

```
func itemBehaviorForView(view: UIView) -> UIDynamicItemBehavior?
{
    func predicate(object: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        if let dynamicItemBehavior = object as? UIDynamicItemBehavior {
            return view === dynamicItemBehavior.items?[0]
        }
        return false
    }

    return animator.behaviors.find(predicate) as? UIDynamicItemBehavior
}
```

I will admit, the casting on the final return statement is a little bit ugly. If animator.behaviors was know to only contains objects of the acceptable return type we could avoid this, but you're likely stuck with this because of the obj-c code.

Comment: behaviors is an Array and if change the extension for NSArray to Array I will get the error:Type annotation does not match contextual type 'T'. also i add he line 'let behaviors: Array = animator.behaviors as Array' before 'return behaviors.find(predicate) as? UIDynamicItemBehavior'.  Thanks